# What are these two common structures that use a set of 6 letters?

Tags: word

Find the two words. These words refer to 2 common structures you might find on a property.

- Structure 1 uses 4 out of the 6 letters, using each of those 4
  letters distinctly once.
- Structure 2 also uses 4 out of the 6 letters, but repeats
  half of those letters exactly once.
- The set of six letters also spell a word for either: a sausage, a lit party.

Comment: Is the 'hint' intended to be part of the puzzle? It seems to me that without it, there are a *ton* of options. And if it's meant to be part of the puzzle proper, it shouldn't be spoilered.

Comment: Can any of those 6 letters repeat?

Answer (score 5):

Some options without using the "hint" (at various levels of stretchiness, in no particular order):

> CLINIC / IRON (as in the Monopoly piece)
>  DONJON / IRON
>  LETTER / FORT
>  ESTATE / SHED
>  CHURCH / BUSH
>  CHURCH / RACK
>  CHURCH / TURF
>  CHURCH / HORN
>  MUSEUM / SEAT
>  MUSEUM / SHED
>  MUSEUM / DUNE
>  MUSEUM / DOME

What I imagine the intended answer is:

> BARN / GARAGE, making the "party" or "sausage" a BANGER.

Answer (score 0):

Without using the hint:

> GATE / GROTTO
>  COTE / TURRET
>  GATE / TURRET
>  COTE / GROTTO